# Wrong React Routing redirect with tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, tabs

I made an error page and redirect to it if the route is incorrect. But when I print smth incorrect in localhost, the browser doesn't redirect to the error page.

```
const allTabs = ["/", "/mylist"];

 <BrowserRouter>  <Route
            path="/"
            render={({ location }) => (
              <>
                <AppBar position="static">
                  <Tabs                  
                    value={location.pathname}
                  >
                    <Tab
                      label="Activity"
                      value="/"
                      component={Link}
                      to={allTabs[0]}
                    />
                    <Tab
                      label="My List"
                      value="/mylist"
                      component={Link}
                      to={allTabs[1]}
                    />
                  </Tabs>
                </AppBar>
                <Switch>
                  <Route path={allTabs[1]} render={() => <MyList />} />
                  <Route
                    path={allTabs[0]}
                    render={() => (
                      <MainPage/>
                    )}
                  ></Route>
                  <Route path="/error" component={ErrorComponent} exact />
                  <Redirect to="/error" />

                </Switch>
              </>
            )}
          />
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Hi! what does it show when it does not redirect to the error page?

Comment: it shows main page with tabs. It does not redirect. I tried to solve the problem by taking out error component from tab route and writing one more after tabs. But I redirect to /activities anytime. <Route path="/error" component={ErrorComponent} exact />

              <Redirect from="/" to="/activities" />
              <Redirect to="/error" />

Comment: Can you reproduce it online in codeSandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-fog-z07bl?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem by enduring main route to the App component. And creating component with tabs.